# Using "contain" function with two arguments in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have a dataset f.ex. like this:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Trust_01_T1 Trust_02_T1 Trust_03_T1 Trust_01_T2 Trust_02_T2 Trust_03_T2 Cont_01_T1 Cont_01_T2
5 1 2 1 5 3 1 1
3 1 3 3 4 2 1 2
2 1 3 1 3 1 2 2
4 2 5 5 3 2 3 3
5 1 4 1 2 2 4 5
")
```

I'd like to use the select function to gather the variables that contain Trust AND T1.

```
dat1 <- dat1 %>%
mutate(Trust_T1 = select(., contains("Trust")))
```

Does anybody know how to use two Arguments there, to have Trust AND T1. If I use:

```
dat1 <- dat1 %>%
mutate(Trust_T1 = select(., contains("Trust"), contains("T1")))
```

it gives me the Variables that contain EITHER Trust or T1.

best!

Comment: Could you clarify what you were trying to accomplish with `mutate()`? Otherwise @akrun's solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(starts_with('Trust') | contains('_T1'))
#>   Trust_01_T1 Trust_02_T1 Trust_03_T1 Trust_01_T2 Trust_02_T2 Trust_03_T2
#> 1           5           1           2           1           5           3
#> 2           3           1           3           3           4           2
#> 3           2           1           3           1           3           1
#> 4           4           2           5           5           3           2
#> 5           5           1           4           1           2           2
#>   Cont_01_T1
#> 1          1
#> 2          1
#> 3          2
#> 4          3
#> 5          4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"
Trust_01_T1 Trust_02_T1 Trust_03_T1 Trust_01_T2 Trust_02_T2 Trust_03_T2 Cont_01_T1 Cont_01_T2 
5 1 2 1 5 3 1 1
3 1 3 3 4 2 1 2 
2 1 3 1 3 1 2 2 
4 2 5 5 3 2 3 3 
5 1 4 1 2 2 4 5
", header =T)
```

Answer (score 2):

If we need both, then use `matches` with a regex to specify the column names that starts (`^`) with 'Trust' and ends (`$`) as 'T1' (assuming these are only patterns

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% 
   select(matches("^Trust_.*T1$"))
```

---

The `mutate` used to create a new column is not clear as there are multiple columns that matches the 'Trust' followed by 'T1'.  If the intention is to do some operations on the selected columns, can either be `across` or `c_across` with `rowwise` (not clear from the post)